# Can you access other program's memory using program compiled with mingw?

Tags: c, windows, operating-system

I wrote this very simple program on Windows 8.1 and compiled it using gcc from Mingw. I ran it with "test.exe > t.txt" and "test.exe > t1.txt" and the outputs were different (even though it uses virtual addresses). It ran for a while and then it crashed. I decided to test this because I'm reading a book on operating systems.

Is it reading other programs' memory? Wasn't that not supposed to happen? I'm probably misunderstanding something...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int r = 0;
    int p[4] = {1,5,4,3};

    for(r=0; p[r]!=1111111111111111; r++){
        p[2] = p[r];
        printf("%d\n", p[2]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SadSeven, I assume you are reading past the end of the array on purpose. What you are seeing is not other programs memory, it's uninitialized memory inside of your programs memory.

Every program runs inside it's own virtual memory space, the os's virtual memory manager takes care of this. You can't access another programs memory from your program (unless you are both using shared memory, but you have to do that on purpose)

Comment: Oh okay, so the output is different because it is uninitialized? Its contents are from other programs ran before? For some reason I assumed that all the contents to where virtual addresses were pointing to would be initialized to null, but wouldn't make much sense... Thank you very much. Still... wouldn't that be a privacy related problem - to see previously used memory spaces?

Comment: Yes and no, it's pretty random what bits of memory you are getting to see. Plus you need to be running on the same physical machine, it's not like a program running on your computer can see bits of left over memory on my computer. Having said that, security sensitive programs will zero out memory after using it to ensure it can't be observed by the next program that happens to land on that page of memory.

Comment: The *OS* will zero out the memory before giving it to another process. Both Windows and *nix (Linux, Unix, OSX) operating systems do this.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck strong claim. Do you have equally strong proof? Win32 `HeapAlloc` without `HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY` will not zero anything...

Comment: If it didn't, you would have a security issue comparable to the heartbleed bug. HeapAlloc allocates from a heap that the process is allowed to access. That means the memory either already belongs to the process or is shared memory.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Your guess may be close to the truth and in some languages the runtime allocation routines may guarantee the zeroed memory (e.g. Delphi, FreePascal), but your "_if it didn't_" opinion is **not verifiable proof** that Windows, Linux, Unix, OSX zero out memory before giving it to a process

Comment: @xmojmr I did a quick google search but only found indications, no proof. For example: "Private process memory is never reused without first being zeroed." in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29449/Windows-Memory-Management

Comment: @KlasLindbäck quick look at [source code of Linux's memory manager](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/mm) shows that it does use `memset(..,0,..)` unconditionally at several (perhaps _key_) places. We people want software to be bullet proof able to drive interstellar robots or life support systems, especially when it comes to OS. All I'm trying to say is that such strong claim that 4 different OS-es do something at the kernel level needs also strong proof. Otherwise it's just misleading not very useful _management_ smalltalk

Answer (score 3):

You haven't initialized anything beyond `p[3]`. The C language makes no guarantees about what will happen when you try to access addresses that haven't been initiazed with data. You'll likely see a bunch of garbage, but what the garbage is isn't defined by the program you wrote. It could be anything.

The addresses you are accessing before the crash still belong to the current process, it is just unitialized memory that exists between the stack and heap.

The process probably crashed due to a segmentation fault, which occurs when a process tries to access memory that doesn't belong to it. This would be the point when it attempts to access outside its own memory.

Answer (score 2):

The output you see is from reading its own memory. When it reaches memory that isn't assigned to the process it crashes.

**Edit:**

To make things harder for computer viruses, the [starting address of a program will be different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) each time you run it. So you should expect different output if you run it several times. [In Windows, the adress space layout is not randomized by all programs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Microsoft_Windows).

Your program overruns a local (auto) variable, which means that it will walk up through the [stack frame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew5tede7.aspx)(s). The stack frame contains local variables, function arguments, saved registers, the return address of the function call, and a pointer to the end of the previous stack frame. If the variables all have the same values any difference would be explained by memory addresses being different. There may be other reasons that I'm not aware of, as I'm not an expert on the memory layout in Windows.

Comment: Hm, that makes sense, but why is the output different on 2 different executions? Shouldn't it be the same?

Comment: I'm sorry for being annoying but I think that doesn't explain it yet. That starting address is a physical address, right? I made another test before that piece of code where I had a static variable and local one, I print their addresses at the start of the program and they are exactly the same (virtual addresses) but the rest of the output is still different on two executions.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `for` loop is erroneous.

```
for(r=0; p[r]!=1111111111111111; r++)
```

it tries to access out of bound memory starting from a value of `4` of `r`. The result is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

It may run fine till `r` is `1997`, it may crash at `r` value `4`, it may start playing a song from your playlist at `r` value `2015`, even. The behaviour is not guaranteed after `r` value `3`.

Comment: I know, that was the point. The program is working as it was supposed too.

Comment: @SadSeven `working as it was supposed to` what do you mean by that?

Comment: That means it was supposed to crash (or do something weird). The question is: why is the output different from two executions of the same program?

Comment: `That means it was supposed to crash (or do something weird).`..not at all. crash (segmentation fault) is ___one of the side effects___ of undefined behaviour. It's not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Each process runs within its separate 4GB virtual address space, attempting an out-of-bounds read won't read from another process's memory. It will read garbage from its own address space. Now, you have been asking about why the output is different, well, ASLR randomises key parts of an executable thereby giving different entry points and stack addresses at instance of a process, thereby even the same process which is run more than once will have different entry points

Read about ASLR at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization
Read about Virtual Memory at:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory